# How do I obtain the size of Large Object Heap programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

I have a helper class which produces performance related statistics at a given interval which includes the process `Private Memory`, `Virtual Memory` `CPU Usage`, number of `GC` collections for each generation and other statistics.

I would like to also include the size of the `LOH` but so far I cannot find any reference on how this can be achieved.

Comment: Use PerformanceCounter, category = ".NET CLR Memory", counter = "Large Object Heap size", instance = yourapp.  Do consider how unnecessary this is, the user can simply run Perfmon.exe

Comment: Thanks Hans, exactly what I needed. FYI this is part of a library monitoring and sending the `Perf` stats of a number of SOA components running on different servers to a central dashboard, hence cannot use `Perfmon`